# Why am I getting the realloc(): invalid next size error for this code?

Tags: c, sizeof, realloc, memory-movement

I have typed this code, and when I compile the code it seems fine but when I execute the executable, as soon as I go to the place corresponding to this file, the app quits and I get `realloc(): Invalid next size Aborted (core dumped)`. Can someone please tell me the correct code and say why? This problem have been vexing me for a while. Oh and `HTFAR` stands for 
*Help topic function array*. So there. I am trying to make a help center for my ripoff of minecraft

```
#include "DisplayHelp.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NOTHING
#define molloc(arg) malloc(arg)
GtkWidget(*List)=NULL;
void (**HTFAR)(void);
uint NumberOfT = 0;

void HelpNewTemplate(const char *Title, const char *Text) {

}

void HelpAbout(void) {
    char *Text ="<span font=\"24\">FakeCraft\n\nCreator: Asadefa\n\nVersion: 1.0.0</span>";
    GtkWidget (*Dialog) = gtk_message_dialog_new(GTK_WINDOW(Window), 1, 0, 2, EMPTYSTRING);
    gtk_message_dialog_set_markup(GTK_MESSAGE_DIALOG(Dialog), Text);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(Dialog), "About");
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(Dialog), 0);
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(Dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(Dialog);
}

void HelpPlacingBlocks(void) {
    printf("sadf\n");
}

void HelpMiningBlocks(void) {
    printf("asdf\n");
}

void HelpCrafting(void) {

}

void HelpSmelting(void) {

}

void HelpShowTopic(void) {
    GtkListBoxRow (*SRow);
    SRow = gtk_list_box_get_selected_row(GTK_LIST_BOX(List));
    if(SRow != NULL NOTHING NOTHING NOTHING NOTHING NOTHING){
        unsigned int NRow = gtk_list_box_row_get_index(SRow);
        (*HTFAR[NRow])();
    }else{

    }
}

void AddHT(const char *Name, GtkWidget (*Label), void(HTF)(void)) {
    const char *TFormat = ("<span font=\"16\">%s</span>");
    char *Format = g_markup_printf_escaped(TFormat, Name);
    Label = gtk_label_new(NULL NOTHING NOTHING NOTHING);
    gtk_widget_set_halign(Label, GTK_ALIGN_START);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_start(Label, 0x0000010);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_top(Label, 0x000008);
    gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom(Label, 0x000008);
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(Label), Format);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(List), Label);
    HTFAR = realloc(HTFAR,sizeof(void*));
    HTFAR[NumberOfT] = &HTF;
    NumberOfT += 0x1;
    printf("Added HT %s\n", Name);
    g_free(Format);
}
//Handle Size 
void DisplayHelp(void) {
    HTFAR = molloc(0x00);
    gtk_main_quit(NOTHING);
    gtk_widget_destroy(Box);
    Box = gtk_grid_new(NOTHING);
    gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(Box), TRUE);
    gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(Box), TRUE);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Window),Box NOTHING);

    List = gtk_list_box_new();
    GtkWidget (*ListC) = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL NOTHING);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(Box),ListC, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x8 NOTHING);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(ListC), 2, 1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(ListC), List);

    GtkWidget (*Label) = NULL;
    GtkWidget (*Button) = NULL;
    GtkWidget (*Hbox) = gtk_box_new(0, 10);
    gtk_box_set_homogeneous(GTK_BOX(Hbox),1);
    Button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Done");
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(Hbox), 12);
    g_signal_connect(Button, "clicked", DisplayOptions, NULL);
    gtk_grid_attach_next_to(GTK_GRID(Box),Hbox,ListC,3, 1, 2);
    gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(Hbox), Button, 1, 1, FALSE);
    AddHT("Placing Blocks", Label, HelpPlacingBlocks);
    AddHT("Mining Blocks", Label, HelpMiningBlocks);
    AddHT("Crafting", Label, HelpCrafting);
    AddHT("Smelting", Label, HelpSmelting);
    AddHT("About", Label, HelpAbout);
    free(HTFAR);

    Button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Show Topic");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(Hbox), Button, 1, 1, FALSE);
    g_signal_connect(Button,"clicked",HelpShowTopic, NULL);

    Label = gtk_label_new(EMPTYSTRING);
    char *TXT  =  ("<span font = \"16\">Help Center</span>");
    gtk_grid_attach_next_to(GTK_GRID(Box),Label,ListC,2,1,1);
    gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(Label), TXT);
    printf(ESSTR, "Help" NOTHING);
    gtk_widget_show_all(Window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

Why is this happening and what is the correct code to type?

Comment: There's a call to `malloc(0)` which is probably incorrect. There's a lot of code here and no hint as to where the problem is. It would help if you can minimize how much you post and help steer us to where you think the problem is, like which function or what line.

Comment: The type of `HTFAR` is rather unusual. What's the intent here? The C notation you're using here is often downright bizarre, like your habit of `X (*y) = ...` when that's typically `X *y = ...` or `X* y = ...` without parentheses. Likewise, `const char *x = ("...")` instead of the conventional `const char* x = "...";`

Comment: `HTFAR = realloc(HTFAR,sizeof(void*));
    HTFAR[NumberOfT] = &HTF;` is very wrong

Comment: This is not a [mcve], not runnable and too much going on...

Comment: @tadman I am trying to make an array of void functions

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you make a minimal, complete, verifiable example that focuses on that behaviour and that behaviour alone. There's a ton of other GTK stuff in here that's completely irrelevant and impedes our understanding of your problem.

Comment: @tadman Oh, but when I try everyone says, this looks like only part of you code gimmie the rest. So when I do A people want B and when I do B they want A

Comment: @tadman and my project is supposed to be closed source so I will edit out those parts

Comment: It's easy to post too little, and it's easy to post too much. That's why we try and steer people towards a *minimal, complete, verifiable example*, as in enough code to completely reproduce the problem and yet not include anything extraneous, as in it compiles and reproduces the problem you're having. In this case focus specifically on your void function allocation issue, make a little demonstration, and we can probably show you how to fix it or an alternate approach that will work.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala How is the line of code you pointed out wrong. It does not suffice to say that it is, but _how_

Comment: As a note, `realloc` takes an argument for the *total size*, not the *incremental additional size*, so here you allocate for precisely one pointer and then go and reference a memory offset that's going to be beyond that as soon as you add two items. `HTFAR[1]` is undefined behaviour. You need `sizeof(void*) * NumberOfT`.

Comment: @tadman I tried that before, and instead I get a segmentation fault

Comment: If you can trim this down to the void function allocation problem the reason that happens will be more clear.

Comment: @tadman That type is right!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [realloc() invalid next size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754985/realloc-invalid-next-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HTFAR = realloc(HTFAR,sizeof(void*));
```

should be

```
HTFAR = realloc(HTFAR,sizeof(void(*)(void))*(NumberOfT+1));
```

You got the specific error you did because `realloc()` moved the block and you overwrote the block after the one returned by (I think) `malloc(0x0)`.